# Sending analog sensor data to laptop at 1kHz via USB

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, analog-sampling

I am reading analog sensor data using Arduino nano, and the required sampling rate is around 1kHz. I am using the AnalogReadSerial example provided by Arduino with a delay of 1ms, so I am expecting to get around 1000 samples per second or slightly less due to the ADC conversion delay. However, the maximum number of samples I am able to get in my laptop a little bit less than 200 samples per seconds. I have tried increasing the baud rate to 115200 but that was not helpful. Am I missing something here, or is there something I need to do to get my data at the required sampling rate?

Below is AnalogReadSerial code I used for reference:

```
// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(1);        // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

Comment: record the value of `millis()` before and after `int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);` ... then print the two  values

Comment: @jsotola I used micros(), and it takes 116 microseconds.

Comment: 115kBaud should actually be enough. 1000 Messages with about 6 bytes each (a 4 digit number and CR/LF) use 6000 bytes or 60000 bits/second. How fast can you get if you remove the delay?

Comment: Running your code on my Uno gives me 791.5 samples/s. Maybe your laptop is too slow to cope with the data rate?

Comment: Rookie mistake from me, I had to accordingly adjust the baud rate of my laptop's USB port using `ssty` because the default was 9600. Right now, I am getting data at a rate similar to yours @Edgar Bonet, which is better but still a little bit shy of the required rate. @PMF your calculations make sense and this baudrate should be within my laptop's and Arduino nano's limits, which is still confusing to me. I will remove the delay and check if that makes any difference.

Comment: since serial uses ascii, it might be less data to send the delta between each reading than the whole number. eg. `128,129,127` is 11 chars, `128,1,-2` is only 8 chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, your code on my Uno gives me
791.5 samples/s. This is about 1263 µs per sample:

- about 110 µs for `analogRead()`, including 104 µs for the
  conversion proper
- presumably 1000 µs for `delay(1)`
- 153 µs for the rest of the code, mostly formatting `sensorValue`
  in ASCII

According to these timings, if it were not for the call to `delay()`,
the Arduino should be able to complete the loop in one millisecond, and
still have 737 µs to spare. The simplest way to achieve this is to
follow the [Blink Without Delay](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/digital/BlinkWithoutDelay) strategy:

```cpp
void loop() {
    static uint32_t last_conversion_time = micros();
    if (micros() - last_conversion_time >= 1000) {
        last_conversion_time += 1000;
        Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
    }
}
```

This does give me 1000 samples per second. Note that
`last_conversion_time` is updated by adding 1000 µs rather than
setting it to `micros()`, so this is actually a variation on the Blink
Without Delay strategy. Updating `last_conversion_time` in this fashion
ensures that whenever the program gets late and misses the exact
microsecond it wanted, the small timing errors do not accumulate.

For the maximum possible timing accuracy, it would be more appropriate
to trigger the ADC by a timer, but that approach is more complex and
requires carefully reading the datasheet of the microcontroller.

Comment: I would not call it BlinkWithoutDelay strategy. It is different. It would be better to initialize last_conversion_time with micros() so it doesn't have to catch up with 1ms increments the time lost in setup() .

Comment: @Juraj: I edited the answer to account for your comments. I would usually prefer letting `last_conversion_time` be initialized to zero, unless `setup()` is really slow (not the case here): this saves the cost of a guard variable and a test at each loop iteration. But then, maybe I tend to micro-optimize too much...